# How to change name variable "let" if I created it early?

Tags: javascript

I need help. I create variable "a", I must change to "oneNumbers", but without  delete old variable.

```
let a = 10;   
let b = 12;    
let suma = a+b;    
console.log(suma);
```

Comment: just do `let oneNumbers = a`?

Answer (score 0):

You can't change a variable name once you have created it. What you can do is either:

**Change the variable value**

```
let a = "A";
a = "B";
console.log(a === "A"); // false
console.log(a === "B"); // true
```

or

**Copy the variable value into a new variable with a different name**

```
let a = "A";
let oneNumbers= a;
console.log(oneNumbers === a); // true
console.log(oneNumbers === "A"); // true
// but
a = "B";
console.log(a === "B"); // true
console.log(oneNumbers === a); // false
console.log(oneNumbers === "A"); // true
```